# Cannot get 'getNegotiatedProtocol' of null when requesting via https in request.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, openssl, request

I'm doing http request using [request.js](http://github.com/request/request), and I have run my program for a very long time this is the first time got this kind of error, it seems related to openssl and TLS issue. Does anybody have idea?

```
2017-02-20T14:27:34.330Z - error: Error: write EPROTO 140125135710016:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:365:
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:801:14)    2017-02-20T14:27:34.332Z - warn: worker warning, msg={"code":"EPROTO","errno":"EPROTO","syscall":"write"}
2017-02-20T14:27:34.348Z - error: uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'getNegotiatedProtocol' of null , 
    version=v6.9.5, 
    argv=[/usr/bin/nodejs, /home/bda/tm/worker.js],rss=234672128, heapTotal=135876608, heapUsed=107730496, loadavg=[0.43798828125, 0.5263671875, 0.53857421875], uptime=906959, 
    trace=[column=36, file=_tls_wrap.js, function=TLSSocket._finishInit, line=588, method=_finishInit, native=false, column=38, file=_tls_wrap.js, function=TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone, line=433, method=ssl.onhandshakedone, native=false], stack=[TypeError: Cannot read property 'getNegotiatedProtocol' of null,     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:588:36),     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:433:38)]
```

Comment: You might post about this on the [node.js issue tracker](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues), it looks like the tls module could use some additional guards/checks.

Comment: @mscdex Haha, it's you again, :)  I posted here because I'm afraid that this is kind of question issue. Anyway, see https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11475

Comment: Error 0x1408F10B, wrong version number, usually means you should stop using SSLv2 or SSLv3, and start using TLS. With ancient versions of the library, like OpenSSL 0.9.8 distributed with OS X, it means you should update the library.

Comment: @jww Thanks, but why it didn't show this in each request